# Setting the Disabled background image for a Checkbox

Tags: android, checkbox, android-drawable

I have created a drawable selector xml file that my checkboxes reference. The ON and OFF selections work fine, but the disabled selector does nothing when I programmatically disable the view. What is the correct way to set the image for the disabled state within the xml selector?

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_on" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_off" android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_disabled" android:state_enabled="false"/>

</selector>
```

Java Code:

```
CheckboxAppDaily.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Move the bottom one to the top, so it checks for enabled before its checked state.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can follow my coding, you should take 2 parameters to meet you requirement.

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
> <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
> <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/pay_bg_rectangle_selected" />
> <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/pay_bg_rectangle_unselected" />
> <item android:state_enabled="false" android:state_checkable="false" android:drawable="@drawable/pay_bg_rectangle_disable" /> 
> </selector>
> ```

Comment: Please add enough description with your answer.